# Why does my Price column show in e-multiples?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

#### I used this method to clean up the currency column of my data of "£" and ",". Also converted the non str values to NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

### Reading the excel file with dtype
df = pd.read_excel("Housing Market B16+5Miles.xlsx", dtype={"Price" : str})
df.loc[df['Price'] == 'POA','Price'] = np.nan

House_Price = df["Price"].str.replace(",","").str.replace("£","").astype("float")

del df['Price']

df["Price"] = House_Price
df

df.describe()
```

by describing the dataframe, the column for the "Price" was all in decimals with an e-value at the end. Why did this happen and will it affect my analysis moving forward?

Comment: I tried to check for the mean "Prices" on a different line using "price.mean()" and it gave me this figure 265049.09823677584.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pandas settings might be set to display large numbers in scientific notation. You can change that using `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)`